# ssh video streaming to VLC on a mac

Tags: ssh, osx-lion, vlc-media-player, streaming, freebsd

I've been looking for how to do this for about a week now over 4 forums.  I have a mac laptop and a FreeBSD server at home.  I've been putting up some of my movies on my server.  When I want to watch a video, on my other computers (running linux) I just use:

```
ssh user@server "cat /dir_to_video/video.avi" | vlc -
```

This opens up vlc with a ssh stream of the video of my choosing.  However, if I run this on my mac, it gives me an error.  Streams the video's coding but doesn't open the video.  Any idea of how I can stream this video to my mac?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you mount the FreeBSD directory locally using `sshfs` or `nfs` or whatever?

Comment: What's the error exactly? What command line version of `vlc` do you have? Or why not use a DLNA/UPnP server on the FreeBSD machine?

Comment: Error was a lack of a better term.  It just dumped the non-human readable coding.

Comment: Terdon, I like the idea of using sshfs.  I didn't think of that.  I might do that.  Thank you.

Comment: Which version of vlc is installed on your mac?

Answer (score 0):

Using Transmit 4 I can mount my SFT(SSH) favorites on my file server to the file system.
It's pretty neat. See this screenshot:

[image]

Btw, on the Ubuntu desktop, you can achieve the same with the [Gigolo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gigolo/) app.